# Irritating blank space between Title Bar and Tabs in Xamarin.Forms UWP project

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm practically new to *Xamarin.Forms* and I'm developing a rather simple cross-platform application. The app displays good enough in Android, but in UWP there is a stupid blank space. The project consists of a TabbedPage with 4 NavigationPages inside it, in order to push and pop pages inside them.

After a little digging into UWP platform specifics, I was able to change the style of my tabs. I've been looking 3 days now for a solution, and it's driving me crazy. The only solution that I have found so far (with the help of Live Visual Tree from VS 2015), is to change the **Visibility** property to **"Collapsed"** from a CommandBar (as shown in the 3rd attached photo). But that's not a solution, because it dissapears, only at runtime.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

[Android View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QljbZ.png), [UWP View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArKzP.png), [Live Visual Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENBmm.png)

**EDIT:**
My *MainPage.xaml* code is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_TIF_Xamarin;assembly=_TIF_Xamarin"
            x:Class="_TIF_Xamarin.MainPage">

  <!--4 different tabs, which also are Navigation Pages-->
  <NavigationPage Title="Home">
    <x:Arguments>
      <local:HomePage />
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>

  <NavigationPage Title="Exhibitor">
    <x:Arguments>
      <local:ExhibitorsPage />
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>

  <NavigationPage Title="Exhibits">
    <x:Arguments>
      <local:ExhibitsPage />
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>

  <NavigationPage Title="More">
    <x:Arguments>
      <local:MorePage />
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>

</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Could you please post the Xamarin.Forms XAML layout you are using for the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom `TabbedPage` and then a UWP renderer for it.

First you create a `CustomTabbedPage` in the PCL:

```
public class CustomTabbedPage : TabbedPage { }
```

In your XAML, use this `CustomTabbedPage` instead of the `TabbedPage`. All behavior and UI will stay the same on all platforms.

Now you create a renderer in the UWP project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]

namespace App.UWP
{

    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            Control.TitleVisibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

We use the `FormsPivot.TitleVisibility` to hide the `Title` area.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your time. I was hoping to avoid custom renderer, but now I can see it's really necessary. I'll let you know about your suggestion.

Comment: I did everything exactly as you told me to, but in _this_ line:
`Control.TitleVisibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;`
the VS2015 shows me an error message:
_Error CS1061 'FormsPivot' does not contain a definition for 'TitleVisibility' and no extension method 'TitleVisibility' accepting a first argument of type 'FormsPivot' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)_

Sorry to bother you again

Comment: Is it possible that you don't have the latest version of the Xamarin.Forms installed from NuGet? I have checked the Xamarin.Forms GitHub and the property should be there indeed, so it is quite confusing :-)  - https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT.Phone/FormsPivot.cs

Comment: I can't thank you enough my friend. That was the problem, and now that space is gone. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Awesome :-) ! Happy coding!